# remove all argument from a list that start with a letter

Tags: python, list

i have a problem with python list:
in the file I have to insert a function that takes as argument a path of a folder and that returns a list of strings with the complete path of the image files inside the folder that I go to specify, excluding all images whose file name does not start by number.
I wrote this code but I can’t get it to work. Any advice? (image files are of two types or numbers as names, or start with 'r', but I should make a generic function for each letter!)
'''

```
import os
import numpy as np


def funzione(folder: str) -> list:
    files = []
    for (root, dirs, file) in os.walk(folder):
        for f in file:
            if f.startswith("r"):
                pass
            else:
                files.append(os.path.join(root, f):
                print(np.shape(file))
                return file

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = './data/fruits/training/Pear 2'
    print(funzione(folder=path))
```

'''

Comment: _but I can’t get it to work_ Saying "it doesn't work" is not a helpful description of the problem.  If you're getting errors, or unexpected output, you have to show us.

Comment: Move `return file` from the `else` to just outside the `for`

Comment: `files.append(os.path.join(root, f):` is a clear syntax error.  The colon at the end should be a closing parentheses.

Comment: @JohnGordon i fixed the *return file* on in the for, but it print me all the Image that i have in the folder and don't remove the file that starts with letter

Comment: @JohnGordon i have also fixed the parentesis that was a mistake in the copy-paste on stack, i'm sorry

Comment: The list of files is named `files`, so shouldn't you have `return files`, not `return file`?

Comment: THAT WAS THE MISTAKE OMG! i add a print for the shape and now is correct

Comment: but i also have a question, in this case i remove all the file that starts with "r", how can i remove the file that start with a letter?

Comment: Change the function so that it takes another argument.  Then use that argument instead of a plain "r".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues:

```py
import os
import numpy as np


def funzione(folder: str) -> list:
    files = []
    for (root, dirs, file) in os.walk(folder):
        for f in file:
            if f.startswith("r"): # <- if else not needed. use not f.startswith('r')
                pass
            else:
                files.append(os.path.join(root, f): # <- missing append closure )
                print(np.shape(file))
                return file # <- stops the for loop after one iteration

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = './data/fruits/training/Pear 2'
    print(funzione(folder=path))
```

How it should look like:

```py
import os
import numpy as np


def funzione(folder: str) -> list:
    files = []
    for root, dirs, file in os.walk(folder):
        for f in file:
            if not f.startswith("r"):
                files.append(os.path.join(root, f)):
                print(np.shape(file))
    return files

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = './data/fruits/training/Pear 2'
    print(funzione(folder=path))
```

you can use a tuple of values as argument for the `startswith` method like:

`f.startswith(('a', 'b', 'c', ..., 'z', '1', ...))`

It will work like an `or` if starts with 'a' or 'z'...